# Не работает наследование

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, наследование

```py
class Cars():
    """Инициализация метода"""
    def __init__(year, size, typE):
        self.year = year
        self.size = size
        self.typE = typE


#super помогает связать родителя и потомка

class Bus(Cars):
    """Аспекты автобуса"""
    def __init__(self, year, size, typE):
        """Инициализация атрибутов родителя"""
        super().__init__(year, size, typE)
        self.capacity = 30

    def description_capacity(self):
        """Выводит инфу о вметимости"""
        print("этот автомобиль вмещает 30 человеков")


Zil = Bus("Зил", "20 век", "большой размер", "автобус",)
Zil.description_capacity()
```

Bыдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Почему Вы у `Bus` указали параметр `self` в `__init__`, а у `Cars` нет?

Comment: Поставил,не помогло

Comment: Так у вас в конструкторе три параметра, а передаете 4. Добавьте в `def __init__` параметр `name`, следуя логике.

Comment: всё равно не работает

Comment: В оба конструктора name добавили после self?

Comment: @CrazyElf, зачем в два? Можно и с одним.

Answer (score 6):

Hу во первых, в классе `Car`, `__init__` у вас вовсе не конструктор:

- вы не передали в него экземпляр класса, т.е `self`.
- вы передаете в него 4 аргумента, когда расcчитан он на 3.

```py
class Cars():
    """Инициализация метода"""
    def __init__(self, name, year, size, typE):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.size = size
        self.typE = typE


#super помогает связать родителя и потомка

class Bus(Cars):
    """Аспекты автобуса"""
    def __init__(self, name, year, size, typE):
        """Инициализация атрибутов родителя"""
        super().__init__(name, year, size, typE)
        self.capacity = 30

    def description_capacity(self): # этот метод может быть статическим
        """Выводит инфу о вметимости"""
        print("этот автомобиль вмещает {} человеков".format(self.capacity))


Zil = Bus("Зил", "20 век", "большой размер", "автобус",)
Zil.description_capacity()
```

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор ожидает что вы ему передадите 3 аргумента, а вы передаете 4, соответственно нужно задать какую-то переменную вроде `name` + не забыть ее передать и в `super().__init__(..)`

```
class Cars():
    """Инициализация метода"""
    def __init__(self, name, year, size, typE):
        self.name = name  # <----
        self.year = year
        self.size = size
        self.typE = typE


# super помогает связать родителя и потомка
class Bus(Cars):
    """Аспекты автобуса"""
    def __init__(self, name, year, size, typE):
        """Инициализация атрибутов родителя"""
        super().__init__(name, year, size, typE)    # <-- указываем все, что нам нужно взять из конструктора родителя
        self.capacity = 30

    def description_capacity(self):
        """Выводит инфу о вметимости"""
        print("этот автомобиль вмещает 30 человеков")


Zil = Bus("Зил", "20 век", "большой размер", "автобус")
Zil.description_capacity()
```